# References for discontinuous Galerkin method with one dimensional case?

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, galerkin-methods

Could anyone recommend some references on discontinuous Galerkin method for beginners? It is nice to contain the one-dimensional case. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are a selection of books you could look at:

- B. Cockburn, G. E. Karniadakis and C.-W. Shu (eds.), Discontinuous Galerkin methods. Theory, computation and applications, Lecture Notes in Computational Science and Engineering, 11. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 2000.
- P. Lesaint, and P. A. Raviart. "On a finite element method for solving the neutron transport equation." Mathematical aspects of finite elements in partial differential equations 33 (1974): 89–123.
- D.A. Di Pietro and A. Ern, Mathematical Aspects of Discontinuous Galerkin Methods. Mathématiques et Applications, Vol. 69, Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 2011.
- J.S. Hesthaven and T. Warburton, Nodal Discontinuous Galerkin Methods: Algorithms, Analysis, and Applications. Springer Texts in Applied Mathematics 54. Springer Verlag, New York, 2008.
- B. Rivière, Discontinuous Galerkin Methods for Solving Elliptic and Parabolic Equations: Theory and Implementation. SIAM Frontiers in Applied Mathematics, 2008.

I would imagine that they contain the 1D case on the whole - I am in the process of looking at them also.